# is it recommended to reference tables from different db?

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys

When working a large project one of the idea is to have everything modular. Now the is with database(s) design. Existing database needs to be redesigned (it has more than 200 tables) and one of suggestion is to make separate databases for each module. Problem with this approach is that many of tables are related, so if some tables would be moved to another database, part of them would have reference (id) to another database. Is this even recommended approach or it's better to keep everything in one database?

If this approach is normal, then how to take care of referential integrity and what are best practices?

Comment: I would not use a separate database for each module. That just doesn't make much sense. 200 tables is nothing for a modern system. That is actually fairly small. I would never even attempt to have related tables be in different databases. That will cause you nothing but massive pain.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for most of your question is unfortunately just going to be "it depends". There is no setup that is best for any shop. Expansion of the database may be a concern. If one module grows exponentially but is not widely used (A History Module) while another has frequent reads but little growth (A User Account Module) it may be more cost efficient to put the high growth module on a machine with HDDs and the high read module on SSDs if cost is an issue for your company. there are obviously other concerns but this is the one I can think of off the cuff.

The only solid answer you can get is mainly related to your question on foregin keys and references. The way you will need to handle it in the multi DB senario will be to use triggers. Triggers on each table would be used to enforce referential integrity between the databases as you can not use foreign key relationships between databases.